# Java RMI - Extend as remote "defined" interface (illegal remote method encountered)

Tags: java, networking, interface, rmi

I have a interface called `MessageReceiver` which is extending `java.rmi.Remote` to be able to be exported by `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj)`.
There is only one single method defined: `public boolean receive(Message msg) throws RemoteException;`

Next, I have a interface called `MessageProvider` which has a single public method named `take()`. This method throws an `InterruptedException` (as it is intended to be blocking).

To implement my needed functionality (a buffer), I have the class `QueueMessageBuffer` which has some sort of queue to enqueue a message. Obviously, this buffer *"IS A"* `MessageReceiver` **and** *"IS A"* `MessageProvider`.

So this was my first step:

```
public class QueueMessageBuffer implements MessageReceiver, MessageProvider
{
  // ...
  public boolean receive(Message m) throws RemoteException
  {
    // ...
  }
  public Message take() throws InterruptedException
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

With this class definition, the following works fine:

```
UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(new QueueMessageBuffer(), 0);
```

But because I have another class, which is using 1 instance as **both** `MessageReceiver` and `MessageProvider`, I tried to couple those two interfaces. Therefore, I created

```
public interface MessageBuffer extends MessageReceiver, MessageProvider {}
```

with `QueueMessageBuffer` furthermore only implementing `MessageBuffer`.

This seemed to be correct to me, but now `exportObject` is giving me an exception:

> java.rmi.server.ExportException: remote object implements illegal remote interface;
>   nested exception is: 
>          java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal remote method encountered: public abstract oertwig.rmichat.net.NetworkMessage oertwig.rmichat.net.MessageProvider.take() throws java.lang.InterruptedException
>          at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.exportObject(UnicastServerRef.java:198)
>          at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:310)
>          at java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(UnicastRemoteObject.java:252)

The question is simple: Why? How do I solve it maintaining a sensible hierarchy but without that exception?

Answer (score 2):

The method take() is not declared as capable of throwing [RemoteException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/rmi/RemoteException.html). This declaration is mandatory so the interface with method without it is illegal. RemoteException is thrown during a number of communication problems that may occur during the execution of a remote method call

Comment: Sorry, I forgot: The method take should NOT be made available to a remote site. That's why I'm not simply adding `throws RemoteException`. Consider this: A client gets the remote object/stub of one instance of `MessageBuffer`. This means, the client can now execute `receive` on the server, which results in the client transmitting the argument (the message) to the server. If the method `take` would be available remotely, every client that could "send" messages to the server could also remove messages from the server's buffer. This would be insane in terms of security.

Comment: @DanielOertwig "Not simply adding 'throws RemoteException'" isn't a mechanism for preventing remote use of the method. You made that up. It is purely and simply illegal in any interface that extends Remote, which MessageBuffer does, via MessageReceiver. If you don't want it to have to throw RemoteException you must refactor.